# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint . Cannot insert duplicate key

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am quite new to ASP.Net MVC. I have just started learning it so kindly help me as I am stuck at a place. Early response will be highly appreciated.
I am making a registration page. 
Added a SQL database using App_data .Below is the table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RegisterModel]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL primary key , 
    [UserName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Email] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Password] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [ConfirmPassword ] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

)
```

Then added ADO.Net Entity data model for the same.
then I created a controller Account with an action method Index as below:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //using (dbRegisterModelEntities dc = new dbRegisterModelEntities())
        //{
            return View();

        }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(RegisterModel user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (dbRegisterModelEntities dc = new dbRegisterModelEntities())
            {
                dc.RegisterModels.Add(user);
                dc.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");

            }
        }
          return View(user);

      }
```

After creating one user , now I am getting error :

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tmp_ms_x__3214EC0778D493BE'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.RegisterModel'. The
>   duplicate key value is (0). The statement has been terminated.

This error is coming when I am trying to add a second user.

Comment: You must either set value of Id before inserting to Db or set auto increment to 1 for Id field in db

Comment: Side note - you should never need to *store* a password confirmation. Also, you *should* be salting and hashing passwords, not storing them directly.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the id as an identity or set a different value for each user

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RegisterModel]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL primary key  IDENTITY(1,1) , 
    [UserName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Email] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Password] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [ConfirmPassword ] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
)
```

Comment: Thanks Simone!  But I already tried the above thing. If I try this , I am getting another error : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'RegisterModel' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: Then you should put in your adding procedure the following command: "SET IDENTITY_INSERT RegisterModel ON".The alternative is the one I mentioned in the answer: keep the table unchanged and in your procedure set the id as a unique number (SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM RegisterModel)

Comment: Thanks ! How I can change the procedure , I didn't create any .If I try running this "SET IDENTITY_INSERT RegisterModel ON" in my db , it says statement is not recognized. Please help !!

Comment: When you call dc.RegisterModels.Add(user); in some place the system is diong things on SQL, that would be the place, just trrack it down. In any case at this link you can get some more info regarding the identity_insert features: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms188059%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Comment: I deleted my edmx file and again created a ado.net entity model and the issue is resolved.Thanks Simone !

Answer (score 0):

Your Primary Key should probably be an identity column, incrementing by 1 each time.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RegisterModel]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) , 
    [UserName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Email] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Password] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [ConfirmPassword ] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_RegisterModel PRIMARY KEY
    (
       Id
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! But I already tried the above thing. If I try this , I am getting another error : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'RegisterModel' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the ID column both from table and model:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RegisterModel]
(
    [UserName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Email] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [Password] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [ConfirmPassword ] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

the username must be unique so you already have a key field.

Comment: Yes I can do this for particular scenario as I can use username as my key field but I have to apply same thing in other scenarios and I am getting same problem.